# Open encrypted volumes created by LibreCrypt in linux

Tags: linux, encryption, luks

How can I open encrypted volumes created by LibreCrypt on linux? These Volume is created by LibreCrypt on Windows7 and is formatted with fat32.

When I tried opening this volume in Linux through cryptsetup, using the following commands.

```
losetup /dev/loop9 volume.vol
cryptsetup open /dev/loop9 crypt_loop9
```

I get the error,

```
Device /dev/loop9 is not a valid LUKS device.
```

Why am I getting this error?

Aren't LibreCrypt created volumes LUKS compatible?

What is the possible solution?

Comment: Well the website only says that LibreCrypt can _open_ LUKS volumes, but it doesn't mention anything about LUKS being able to open LibreCrypt ones…

Answer (score 4):

LibreCrypt created volumes are not LUKS compatible. They are created in 'FreeOTFE' compatible format.
You can create a LUKS volume in Linux and open it in LibreCrypt.

Answer (score 1):

try:
sudo cryptsetup /dev/mapper/loop9 $desired_name

if that doesn't work then the volume is not LUKS compatible. the solution is to use cryptsetup to create a LUKS compatible volume in linux and mount it in windows with LibreCrypt. that way you can use it in both.

Answer (score 0):

@OP, as a  fellow  observer and  tester for LibreCrypt (linux-modder) you would  open it  with the following command.

> sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/volume  $desired_name

(from your example $desired_name would be  crypt9_loop)

Comment: could u elaborate what is `/dev/mapper/volume` here. AFAIK, it should be a block device such as `/dev/loopX` . When this command is successful, the device wil be unlocked at `/dev/mapper/$desired_name` . And using any of `#cryptsetup open ...` and `#cryptsetup luksOpen ...` gives the same error `Device /dev/loopX is not a valid LUKS device.`

Comment: If it helps, I used Libre Crypt version 6.2 beta on Windows 7 ultimate 64bit to create the volume.